# Multivariable equation for a hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

I have those two equations and i should find the values to make them equal to 0

3x^2+1-4y=0
-4x-4y=0

I find the values x=-1 and y=1 but the book says there should be also another solution but i cannot find it after doing multiple tries.

Comment: surround ur maths equations with dollar signs. learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553). and also, please include what you tried in your future posts.

Answer (score 0):

$$3x^2+1-4y=0$$
$$-4x-4y=0$$

$$y=-x$$

$$3x^2+1+4x=0$$

$$(3x+1)(x+1)=0$$

Hopefully you can see the other solution.

Comment: The solution is -1/3 and +1/3 but i reached that simply by looking and doing a  trial and error in my mind, i cannot find it formally with the equation.

Comment: Nevermind i found it , it's extremely easy i should just be more careful next time.